# What is the difference between Process.terminate() and Process.kill() in Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

What is the difference between `Process.terminate()` and `Process.kill()` in Python multiprocessing?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? What part of it is unclear to you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`terminate()` sends the `SIGTERM` signal to the process

```
terminate():
    Terminate the process. On Unix this is done using the SIGTERM signal; on Windows TerminateProcess() is used. Note that exit handlers and finally clauses, etc., will not be executed.
```

`kill()` sends the `SIGKILL` signal to the process.

```
kill():
Same as terminate() but using the SIGKILL signal on Unix.
```

How the process handles these signals is up to it. Usually, `SIGTERM` is graceful shutdown while `SIGKILL` is more of an abort. [More details](https://major.io/2010/03/18/sigterm-vs-sigkill/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19206124/difference-between-killed-and-terminated